# Necessity of explicit cursor.close()

Tags: python, django, database-connection, database-cursor

From time to time, I'm executing raw queries using [`connection.cursor()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors) instead of using ORM (since it is definitely not a silver bullet).

I've noticed that in several places I don't call explicit `cursor.close()` after I'm done with database. So far, this hasn't result into any errors, or performance issues. I'm wondering what kind of problems could I possibly have without closing the cursor explicitly, what can go wrong?

As far as I understand, `connection` and `cursor` in Django follow "Python Database API Specification v2.0" ([PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249)). And, according to it, `cursor` would be automatically closed whenever `__del__()` method is called. I guess the question could be also: Is there a use case when it is not called?

FYI, I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.5.

Comment: I guess it is very much similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/python-mysqldb-when-to-close-cursors ??

Comment: @AamirAdnan thanks, not quite - seen it before posting. I know how to close the cursor. The question is about how bad it is not to close it and what are the consequences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`__del__`/`.close()`:**

1. `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called
2. some databases don't call cursor.close() in their `__del__` (bad practice, but true)
3. some databases don't actually create connections in the connection function, but in the cursor function instead (e.g. for 2&3: pyhive's presto [maybe they've since patched it])

**On server connections in general**

Most servers have an idle timeout configuration property (let's call that T). If a connection is idle for more than T seconds, the server will remove the connection. Most servers also have properties to set the size of the worker thread pool (W). If you already have W connections to your server, it will likely hang when a new connection is attempted. For a second imagine that you don't have the option to explicitly close connections. In that situation, you have to set the timeout to be small enough that your worker pool is never completely used, which is a function of how many concurrent connections you have.

However, if you do close your cursors/connections (even when not equivalent by [3] above, they behave in a similar way), then you don't have to manage these server configuration properties and your thread pool simply needs to be large enough to manage all concurrent connections (with the option for an occasional wait for new resources). I've seen some servers (e.g. Titan on Cassandra) unable to recover from running out of workers in the thread pool, so the whole server goes down until restarted.

**TL/DR**
If you're using very well-developed libraries, like the ones `dano` mentions, you won't have an issue. If you're using less pristine libraries, you may end up blocking on the server acquiring a worker thread if you don't call `.close()`, depending on your server config and access rates.

Answer (score 26):

Django's `cursor` class is just a wrapper around the underlying DB's `cursor`, so the effect of leaving the `cursor` open is basically tied to the underlying DB driver.

According to psycopg2's (psycopg2 is DB driver Django uses for PostgreSQL DB's) [FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#best-practices), their cursors are lightweight, but will cache the data being returned from queries you made using the cursor object, which could potentially waste memory:

> Cursors are lightweight objects and creating lots of them should not
>   pose any kind of problem. But note that cursors used to fetch result
>   sets will cache the data and use memory in proportion to the result
>   set size. Our suggestion is to almost always create a new cursor and
>   dispose old ones as soon as the data is not required anymore (call
>   close() on them.) The only exception are tight loops where one usually
>   use the same cursor for a whole bunch of INSERTs or UPDATEs.

Django uses `MySQLdb` as the backend for MySQL, which has several different types of cursors, including some that actually store their result-sets on the server-side. The [`MySQLdb` documentation for `Cursor.close`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#cursor-objects) make a point to note that it's very important to close the server-side cursor's when you're done with them:

> If you are using server-side cursors, it is very important to close
>   the cursor when you are done with it and before creating a new one.

However, this isn't relevant for Django, because it uses the default `Cursor` class provided by `MySQLdb`, which stores results on the client-side. Leaving a used cursor open just risks wasting the memory used by the stored result-set, just like `psycopg2`. The [`close` method](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L97) on the cursor just deletes the internal reference to the db connection and exhausts the stored result set:

```
def close(self):
    """Close the cursor. No further queries will be possible."""
    if not self.connection: return
    while self.nextset(): pass
    self.connection = None
```

As best as I can tell from looking at their source, all the remaining backends used by Django ([cx_oracle](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/src/8f26a661ad09fe3f3933ae8b02e73defeec58ada/Cursor.c?at=default#cl-833), [sqlite3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db302b88fdb6/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#l1000)/[pysqlite2](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/master/src/cursor.c#L1039)) all follow the same pattern; free memory by deleting/resetting stored results/object references. The [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) don't even mention that the `Cursor` class *has* a close method, and it's only used sporadically in the included example code.

You are right that a `cursor` will be closed when `__del__()` is called on the `cursor` object, so the need to explicitly close is only an issue if you're keeping a long-living reference to the `cursor`; e.g. a `self.cursor` object that you're keeping as an instance method of a class.

Comment: If you re-use a cursor for a second query, however, the data it cached  for the first query will no longer be referenced. So in one sense creating a whole bunch of cursors unnecessarily might be counter-productive unless you specifically delete the used ones.

Comment: @holdenweb Right, if you're going to be making a whole bunch of queries in a short period of time, it might make sense to use the same cursor. If you're going to make a query, and then at some unknown point in the future make another one, you should probably close/delete the cursor so you don't hold onto whatever memory it's using to cache the result set.

Comment: It appears we have violent agreement.

Comment: The recent changes to how django (1.5+) handles transactions atomically are noteworthy, especially if you are using raw queries very often.

Check out the latest development docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: `contextlib.closing` will ensure cursor closed expectedly and meanwhile the code still looks compact.

Answer (score 2):

While the operating system can normally be relied upon to release resources, it's always good hygiene to close things like database connections to ensure resources are released when no longer required, the really important thing from a database point of view is to ensure that any changes are `commit()`ed.

Answer (score 2):

The explicit calling of `cursor.close()` might be because of two reasons:

1. `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called and has some issues you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) and [here](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/07/07/python-destructor-and-garbage-collection-notes/)
2. Explicit is better than implicit ([Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this question. Maybe a close-on-exit-scope is what you want.

```
from contextlib import closing
from django.db import connection

with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(...)
    cursor.execute(...)
    cursor.execute(...)
```

Comment: They mentioned using Django 1.6 and the docs say a context manager (such as your example) wasn't explicitly added until 1.7, though, the docs seem to indicate that it worked prior to that any way due to "unexpected behavior in magic method lookups".

Comment: I'd agree context manager is definitely the cleanest way to go.