# Python MySQLdb - do I have to close cursors and connections?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Im Python newbie.

I wrote simple script which runs every minute on my Raspberry Pi and it logs some data to MySQL 5.5 database.

Script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
from MyADCPi import ADCPi
import time
import os

con = mdb.connect('localhost','pi','pi','pi')

#initialize MCP3424 ADC in 18 bit mode
adc = ADCPi(18)

# initialize cursor 
cur = con.cursor()

# measure LM35 output voltage and calculate temperature
# 1'C = 10mV, 1V = 100'C
temp = adc.readVoltage(1)*100

# log temperature   
cur.execute("INSERT INTO data(channel, value) values(1,"+str(temp)+")")

# measure MPX4115 voltage and calculate pressure
# (19.5/7.5) is voltage divider
# vs is sensor supply voltage
# (vo/vs + 0.095)/0.0009 comes from formula in MPX4115 datasheet

vo = adc.readVoltage(2)*(19.5/7.5)
vs = 4.8
press = (vo/vs + 0.095)/0.0009

# log pressure
cur.execute("INSERT INTO data(channel, value) values(2,"+str(press)+")")

con.commit()
```

Questions:

1. Im using same cursor object for 2 inserts. Is this OK?
2. Do I have to close connection, cursor etc. or Python will manage this after script ends?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24661754/2073595) for info on the necessity of `cursor.close()`, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's fine.
2. You should close the connection.