# Execute multiple statement on MySQLdb cursor

Tags: python, mysql, cursor, mysql-python

I want to execute multiple statements on a `MySQLdb` cursor over a database with **MyISAM** storage. I followed every other way explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/python-mysqldb-when-to-close-cursors) and elsewhere, unsuccessfully.

```
>>> import MySQLdb as mdb
>>> from contextlib import closing

>>> con = mdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database')

>>> with closing(con.cursor()) as cur:
>>>     cur.callproc('add_date', [1418112000])
>>>     cur.callproc('add_date', [1418119000])
>>>     #con.commit()
>>>     cur.close()

_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Since the storage of tables is **MyISAM**, I should not need to call commit(). In fact if I call `commit()`, I will encounter an error.

What is the correct way to call multiple statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling the procedure, you have to close the cursor and open it again before using it to execute another statement:

```
cur.close()

cur = con.cursor()
```

The cursor can be closed immediately after `fetchall()`. The result set still remains and can be looped through. You have to clean/close the cursor after calling stored procecude in order to execute further sql code. This is not an issue with Python but with MySQL.