# Why doesn't the MySQLdb Connection context manager close the cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, contextmanager

MySQLdb `Connections` have a rudimentary context manager that creates a cursor on *enter*, either rolls back or commits on *exit*, and implicitly doesn't suppress exceptions. From the [Connection source](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py):

```
def __enter__(self):
    if self.get_autocommit():
        self.query("BEGIN")
    return self.cursor()

def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
    if exc:
        self.rollback()
    else:
        self.commit()
```

**So, does anyone know *why* the cursor isn't closed on exit?**

---

At first, I assumed it was because closing the cursor didn't do anything and that cursors only had a close method in deference to the [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods) (see the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618781/484488)). However, the fact is that closing the cursor burns through the remaining results sets, if any, and disables the cursor. From the [cursor source](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py):

```
def close(self):
    """Close the cursor. No further queries will be possible."""
    if not self.connection: return
    while self.nextset(): pass
    self.connection = None
```

It would be so easy to close the cursor at exit, so I have to suppose that it hasn't been done on purpose. On the other hand, we can see that when a cursor is deleted, it is closed anyway, so I guess the garbage collector will eventually get around to it. I don't know much about garbage collection in Python.

```
def __del__(self):
    self.close()
    self.errorhandler = None
    self._result = None
```

---

Another guess is that there may be a situation where you want to re-use the cursor after the `with` block. But I can't think of any reason why you would need to do this. Can't you always finish using the cursor inside its context, and just use a separate context for the next transaction?

To be very clear, this example obviously doesn't make sense:

```
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(select_stmt)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

It should be:

```
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(select_stmt)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Nor does this example make sense:

```
# first transaction
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(update_stmt_1)

# second transaction, reusing cursor
try:
    cursor.execute(update_stmt_2)
except:
    conn.rollback()
else:
    conn.commit()
```

It should just be:

```
# first transaction
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(update_stmt_1)

# second transaction, new cursor
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(update_stmt_2)
```

**Again, what would be the harm in closing the cursor on exit, and what benefits are there to not closing it?**

Comment: A good explanation for this >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/when-to-close-cursors-using-mysqldb

Comment: @syed That is an old question of mine, which I also link to in this question!

Comment: Oops! Didn't notice that. I guess that explanation still holds. No concrete answer to this, other than this that you need to make sure on your own.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the `MySQLdb` source gives relatively little insight into the underlying `_mysql` module (distributed with `MySQLdb` as a `.pyd` binary) or [the API it implements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html). I tend to assume that either the package author ran into a reason to do things this way, buried in one of those dependencies, or that it began as YAGNI and ended up as "ain't broke."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question directly: I cannot see any harm whatsoever in closing at the end of a `with` block.  I cannot say why it is not done in this case.  But, as there is a dearth of activity on this question, I had a search through the code history and will throw in a few thoughts (***guesses***) on why the `close()` ***may*** not be called:

1. There is a small chance that spinning through calls to `nextset()` may throw an exception - possibly this had been observed and seen as undesirable.  This may be why the [newer version of `cursors.py`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/1.3.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L86) contains this structure in `close()`:

   ```
   def close(self):
       """Close the cursor. No further queries will be possible."""
       if not self.connection:
           return

       self._flush()
       try:
           while self.nextset():
               pass
       except:
           pass
       self.connection = None
   ```
2. There is the (somewhat remote) potential that it might take some time to spin through all the remaining results doing nothing.  Therefore `close()` may not be called to avoid doing some unnecessary iterations.  Whether you think it's worth saving those clock cycles is subjective, I suppose, but you could argue along the lines of "if it's not necessary, don't do it".
3. Browsing the sourceforge commits, the functionality was added to the trunk by [this commit](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/code/ci/f6a0ff1ca04339387999ab490c8c0abaf011d5e4/) in 2007 and it appears that this section of `connections.py` has not changed since.  That's a merge based on [this commit](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/svn/480/), which has the message

   > Add Python-2.5 support for with statement as described in http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/pep-343.html *Please test*

   And the code you quote has never changed since.

   This prompts my final thought - it's probably just a first attempt / prototype that just worked and therefore never got changed.

---

#### More modern version

You link to source for a legacy version of the connector.  I note there is a more active fork of the same library [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python), which I link to in my comments about "newer version" in point 1.

Note that the more recent version of this module has implemented `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` within `cursor` itself: [see here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/1.3.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L86).  `__exit__()` here ***does*** [call `self.close()`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/1.3.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L103) and perhaps this provides a more standard way to use the with syntax e.g.

```
with conn.cursor() as c:
    #Do your thing with the cursor
```

---

#### End notes

***N.B.*** I guess I should add, as far as I understand garbage collection (not an expert either) once there are no references to `conn`, it will be deallocated. At this point there will be no references to the cursor object and it will be deallocated too.

***However*** calling `cursor.close()` does not mean that it will be garbage collected.  It simply burns through the results and set the connection to `None`.  This means it can't be re-used, but it won't be garbage collected immediately.  You can convince yourself of that by manually calling `cursor.close()` after your `with` block and then, say, printing some attribute of `cursor`

---

***N.B. 2*** I think this is a somewhat unusual use of the `with` syntax as the `conn` object persists because it is already in the outer scope - unlike, say, the more common `with open('filename') as f:` where there are no objects hanging around with references after the end of the `with` block.

Comment: Yes, `with conn.cursor() as c` does make more sense and I'm glad that it in fact is closed in that version. I will probably try switching over to that version. It's a moot issue at this point, but my note about garbage collection is that the close would be called during collection anyway so why bother (rather than whether and when it would be collected). If I had to guess, your #3 seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: OK - yeah - I see your point about `close` being called during garbage collection: you're right and I'd misunderstood the point you were making.  Thanks for the bounty, though - sorry I couldn't give a definitive, but I agree #3 is probably the most likely.

Comment: I realize this is an old question and answer, but I think it's worth noting that the `__exit__` method shown in the question gets called on the `Connection` object, not on the `Cursor` object that was returned from the `__enter__` method. This is unlike Python's file objects, which return `self` from `__enter__`. Because `Connection.__enter__` doesn't save a reference to the `Cursor` it returns (at least, not as part of `__enter__` directly), there's no obvious way for `__exit__` to be able to close it. Doing `self.close()` would probably not be appropriate!