# Why is __del__ called at the end of a with block?

Tags: python, mysql-python, with-statement

The scope of the variables created in a `with` statement is outside the `with` block (refer: [Variable defined with with-statement available outside of with-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432355/variable-defined-with-with-statement-available-outside-of-with-block)). But when I run the following code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print "__int__() called."

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__() called."

    def __enter__(self):
        print "__enter__() called."
        return "returned_test_str"

    def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
        print "__exit__() called."

    def close(self):
        print "close() called."

    def test(self):
        print "test() called."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Foo() as foo:
        print "with block begin???"
        print "with block end???"

    print "foo:", foo  # line 1

    print "-------- Testing MySQLdb -----------------------"
    with MySQLdb.Connect(host="xxxx", port=0, user="xxx", passwd="xxx", db="test") as my_curs2:
        print "(1)my_curs2:", my_curs2
        print "(1)my_curs2.connection:", my_curs2.connection
    print "(2)my_curs2.connection:", my_curs2.connection
    print "(2)my_curs2.connection.open:", my_curs2.connection.open  # line 2
```

The output shows that `Foo.__del__` is called before printing foo (at `# line 1` above):

```
__int__() called.
__enter__() called.
with block begin???
with block end???
__exit__() called.
__del__() called.
foo: returned_test_str
-------- Testing MySQLdb -----------------------
(1)my_curs2: <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7f16dc95b290>
(1)my_curs2.connection: <_mysql.connection open to 'xxx' at 2609870>
(2)my_curs2.connection: <_mysql.connection open to 'xxx' at 2609870>
(2)my_curs2.connection.open: 1
```

My question is, why is `Foo.__del__` called here, if the `with` statement does not create a new execution scope?

Also, if the connection's `__del__` method is called in the second `with` block, I don't understand why `my_curs1.connection` is still open afterward (see `# line 2` above).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use with statement with MySQLdb.Connection object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751703/can-i-use-with-statement-with-mysqldb-connection-object)

Comment: Chengcheng, see @tzaman's link for the answer to your second issue, and remove that part from your question. Keeping one issue to one question helps keep StackOverflow tidy and enables people to find answers more quickly. Thank you!

Comment: @tzaman That question is 3 years old and its answer is incorrect.

Comment: True - this is an interesting question.  There's a more up to date discussion of `mysqldb` context manager [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374857/why-doesnt-the-mysqldb-connection-context-manager-close-the-cursor). @air is right - the linked duplicate is out of date

Comment: @JRichardSnape The post is different from mine. I know why cursor is not closed. because with-statement does not call close(). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/when-to-close-cursors-using-mysqldb

Comment: @ChengchengPei Yes - I know it's different.  I was trying to prevent your question getting closed as a duplicated of as suggest by @tzaman, because the answer there is out of date.  I was unaware of the link you provided until 15 mins ago.  I can only guess at why `__del__` is called, but I can tell you it's prompting some discussion in the Python chatroom - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to note that `foo` is not an object of type `Foo`.  You do create a `Foo` and need to keep it around because it might contain state information needed to call `__exit__`.  But once that's done, the object is unneeded and Python's free to throw it away.

Put another way, this:

```
with Foo() as foo:
    print ('Hello World!')
```

Is the same as this:

```
_bar = Foo()
foo = _bar.__enter__()
print ('Hello World!')
_bar.__exit__()
del _bar # This will call __del__ because _bar is the only reference
```

The behavior you are expecting would happen if `foo` were a reference to the `with` block's foo.  For example...

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print ("__int__() called.")

    def __del__(self):
        print ("__del__() called.")

    def __enter__(self):
        print ("__enter__() called.")
        return self # foo now stores the Foo() object

    def __str__(self):
        return 'returned_test_str'

    def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
        print ("__exit__() called.")

    def close(self):
        print ("close() called.")

    def test(self):
        print ("test() called.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Foo() as foo:
        print ("with block begin???")
        print ("with block end???")

    print ("foo:", foo)  # line 1
```

Prints

```
__int__() called.
__enter__() called.
with block begin???
with block end???
__exit__() called.
foo: returned_test_str
__del__() called.
```

---

I have no idea why `Connection.__exit__` would leave its cursors open however.

Comment: "with closing( self.__conn.cursor() ) as cur:"" will call close(), but not __exit__() and __enter__(). But with-statement will call __exit__() and __enter__(), but not close(). Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/when-to-close-cursors-using-mysqldb

Comment: I just wonder why __del__() is called before print statement (line1 in my post). I make sense to me if __del__() is called when program exit.

Comment: `__del__` is being called because there are no more references to the temporary object constructed by the `with` block.  Remember, `foo` is not the `Foo()` you made.

Comment: That makes sense to me now if python does gc before program exits. Thanks.

Comment: Technically it can do what it wants, but in practice yea it cleans up as soon as you don't have any more references to an object.