# PyPyOdbc Correct use of cursor

Tags: python, pypyodbc

I use pypyodbc to read data from an ms sql server.

I am not sure if the cursor should be closed after any query or just once at the end and I could not find anything in the doc.

Example:

```
curs = con.cursor()

for id in id_list:
    curs.execute ('Select * from XXX where id = {}'.format (id))
    curs.fetchall ()
    # Write the data into the target...
    # curs.close() ???

curs.close()
```

Is this correct?

thanks

Comment: close the cursor when you're done with it.

Comment: If it implements the standard PEP for cursors (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) , then related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669878/when-to-close-cursors-using-mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

The `with` keyword is what you are looking for

```
with sqlite3.connect("db.db") as DB:
    cursor = DB.cursor()
    #...perform sql
# connection automatically closes
```