# Is there any difference between closing a cursor or a connection in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

I have been using always the command `cur.close()` once I'm done with the database:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb')
cur = conn.cursor()
# whatever actions in the database
cur.close()
```

However, I just saw in some cases the following approach:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb')
cur = conn.cursor()
# whatever actions in the database
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

And in the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) sometimes the cursor is closed, sometimes the connection and sometimes both.

My questions are:

1. Is there any difference between `cur.close()` and `conn.close()`?
2. Is it enough to close one, once I am done (or I must close both)? If so, which one is preferable?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504340/python-mysqldb-connection-close-vs-cursor-close

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[On closing cursors]*

If you close the cursor, you are simply flagging it as invalid to process further requests ("I am done with this").

So, in the end of a function/transaction, you should keep closing the cursor, giving hint to the database that that transaction is finished.

A good pattern is to make cursors are short-lived: you get one from the connection object, do what you need, and then discard it. So closing makes sense and you should keep using `cursor.close()` at the end of your code section that makes use of it.

I **believe** (couldn't find any references) that if you just let the cursor fall out of scope (end of function, or simply `del cursor`) you should get the same behavior. But for the sake of good coding practices you should explicitly close it.

*[Connection Objects]*

When you are actually done *with the database*, you should close your **connection** to it. that means `connection.close()`