# How to identify open connections in MySQL opened by Python

Tags: python, mysql

MySQL 5.7 shows 3 sleeping processes in the processlist while I run my application. This is preventing Alter Table commands and is kind of worrying me as it will persumably not scale as I deploy more services.

From [Python MySQLdb: connection.close() VS. cursor.close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504340/python-mysqldb-connection-close-vs-cursor-close) I have learned how to close a connection properly in Python. This has fixed 1 sleeping connection (comming from 4), but still there are 3 open.

How can I identify what the connection is causing in order to track down the python code which is not closing it?

Comment: Find the port the connection comes from (`SHOW STATUS`) and on the client check which process opened the connection (`netstat …`).

Comment: Could you please be more specific? The processlist shows the host and I know that is a pyhthon script I started. It is just unclear to me where in the code with all the classes and methods I forgot to close a connection (or where I should close)