# mysql connector and threadting mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 2055: Cursor is not connected

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, mysql-connector-python

I created a web crawler and my app was working without any error before but it was slow, so I decided to make it process two pages in same time using threading, everything working fine until comes to inserting data into database in  **last line in compare function** using **mysql connector**, it keeps throwing this error

```
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 242, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError("Cursor is not connected", 2055)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 2055: Cursor is not connected
```

```
from threading import Thread  
import datetime   
import mysql.connector  

class PostMaker:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
   
    def mysqlconnect(self,):
        db =  mysql.connect(host="localhost",
                        username="root",
                        password="",
                        database ="test"
        )
        cursor =  db.cursor()
        return db , cursor
    
    def createpost(self,page_id,post_name,post_slug,date,post_data):
        db ,cursor = self.mysqlconnect()
        query_1 = f"""INSERT INTO wp_posts (page_id,post_name,post_slug,date,post_data) Values ({page_id},
                "{post_name}","{post_slug}","{date}","{post_data}");"""

        cursor.execute(query_1)
        db.commit()
        post_id = cursor.lastrowid
        return post_id
    
    
       
    def compare(self,new_posts,**kwargs):
        for new_post in new_posts:
            post_slug = kwargs["post_slug"]
            post_name =  "post "+str(new_post)
            
            post_data = kwargs["post_data"]
            date  = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            #  here where the erorr happend
            post_id =  self.createpost(kwargs["page_id"],post_name,post_slug,date,post_data)
          
          
            
    def sub_list(self,id_list):
        sublist = list()
        for i in range(0, len(id_list),4):
            sublist.append(id_list[i:i + 4])
        return sublist  
           
    def page_handler(self,pages):
        for signle_page in pages:
            new_posts , info =  self.page_handler(signle_page)
            new_post =  self.compare(new_posts,**info)

            
    def  run(self):
        big_list=  self.sub_list(self.get_no_scan_data())
        for sub_list in big_list:
            new_thread = Thread(target=self.page_handler,args=(sub_list,))
            new_thread.start()
```

Comment: This URL may be of value to you -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504340/python-mysqldb-connection-close-vs-cursor-close  - from 2011, may still be valid advice.  Not verified by me.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck this not related to my problem , since I'm not trying to clo7the connection but the connection is lost its self

Comment: If you had a connection, how/why did it get lost?  A General Log Analysis may be appropriate to follow the breadcrumbs.  View pofile for contact information, if needed.