# try; finally without except?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Suppose I'm doing some sql query:

```
try:
  some_cursor.execute(sql_query) 
finally:
  some_cursor.close()
```

Is there any difference from the above with:

```
some_cursor.execute(sql_query) 
some_cursor.close()
```

They seem equivalent since there's no exception handling.
I do recall reading that if `some_cursor.execute(sql_query)`  has an error, then the cursor may not be closed properly in the latter close, but the former case's `finally` block would ensure that?

Comment: With try/finally even if the code between try and finally raises an exception, the finally block will still be executed

Comment: @DarkKnight sure, but in this case, it's just closing the cursor right? so I think the 2 are equivalent when an exception is thrown. in the second case, if `some_cursor.execute(sql_query)` fails, then the program will terminate, and the cursor is automatically closed, right?

Comment: In the second block of code, if `execute()` raises and exception then `close()` will not be called as is the case in the first block of code or when using a `with`

Comment: Yes, there is a difference.

Without the try block, if your program encounters an error within the execute method it will terminate before it reaches the close method.

With the try block, when any exception is raised during the execution of any code within that block, the finally block will be executed. Therefore, even if an exception is raised the close method will be called.

It does not matter whether you actually except the exception and handle it accordingly or not, the finally block will always be executed.

Comment: It's useful when the `finally` clause does something that won't happen automatically if the script terminates.

Comment: Note that the script might not terminate when the exception happens. If this code is in a function, there might be some outer `try/except` that catches the exception. It's good design to make your functions behave consistently no matter how they're called.

Comment: `try/finally` is similar to using a context manager to automatically clean up when you leave a block.

Comment: @H.Syd Are you responding to my comment to darkknight or my OP specifically? my comment above is more of a follow up. let's suppose in the latter case (without the try and finally), there's no exception handling of whatever is performing `some_cursor.execute(sql_query)`, in which case, the program would just end. in that case, the cursor gets closed upon termination and the two snippets are equivalent right?

Comment: @roulette01 If no exception is raised when *some_cursor.execute(sql_query)* is invoked then the two code fragments will be functionally equivalent. Think of *finally* as a "clean up" mechanism

Comment: @roulette01 The title of your question is misleading, since you're ***primarily*** asking whether an sql cursor will always eventually be closed regardless of whether an exception occurs. This seems to have already been covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2330344/984421).

Answer (score 1):

The most important (and perhaps obvious) difference is that you are no longer catching exceptions that could happen during the execution of your query. So if `some_cursor.execute(sql_query)` fails, you will never reach the next line (i.e., the cursor will not be closed) because the program will terminate (or exit the outer `try/except` block as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out in the comments). While some database libraries and Python database drivers may automatically close resources when the program exits, relying on this behaviour is not recommended because it can lead to resource leaks and other issues. `finally` contains your "clean-up" commands which will ensure that the cursor will be closed regardless of what happens inside your `try` block.
See [Python's Documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) for more info.